# Facebook like url expander in android

Tags: php, android, url

When we paste a url in Facebook EditText it will auto read and expand the url for us. I want to read and get image and description from an url something like [this](http://w3lessons.info/2013/05/25/facebook-style-youtube-video-vimeo-video-soundcloud-audio-url-expander-with-jquery-php/) just like facebook. In php I can get it with curl but in android how can I make it?

```
eta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=ea71a5211a91" />
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="Ask a Question" />
<meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Facebook like url expander in android"/>
```

In php I get the data above to display the correct image and description to the user so in android is there any other more efficient way?

Comment: What is your question? you posted twitter meta card

Comment: That was an example of what data I would like to return to my android device @AmitThakur